# Can f be continuously extended to zero?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x,y)=e^{xy\log(x^2+y^2)}$$ Can f be extended continuously to $(0,0)$?

I tried to solve it using polar coordinates until I get $\lim_{r\to 0}e^{r^2\cos(\theta )\sin(\theta )\log(r^2)}$, but how to continue? I'm not sure if the estimates $|\sin(\theta )|,|\cos(\theta )|\le 1$ for real $\theta$ will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In polars we get
$$\ln f(x,y)=2r^2(\cos t\sin t)\ln r=r^2\sin(2t)\ln r.$$
This is between $\pm r^2|\ln r|$. Now $r^2\ln r\to0$ as $r\to 0$.
So $f(x,y)\to1$.